# How do I find out the meaning of a symbol in Haskell?

Tags: mongodb, haskell

I'm using the `mongoDB` extension and at some point I saw this

```
["author" =: "Mike"]
```

I want to know what `=:` does. How do I find it out? There is no way to google that.

I tried importing the module into `ghci` and doing `:t (=:)`, but the `=:` function is not exposed by mongoDB, it is just used by it, so I'm still getting `variable not in scope`.

How do I find out the meaning and signature of functions without helpful names like this one?

Comment: How would you find it out if it said `[lklkjaaaaaa "author" "Mike"]`? Probably by grepping for `lklkjaaaaaa`. So grep for `(=:)` or `=:`

Comment: You’re right—you can’t google that, but [you sure can Hoogle it](http://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%3D%3A). It looks like your `=:` is [the one from the bson package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bson-0.3.2.3/docs/Data-Bson.html#v:-61-:).

Comment: you can always try hoogle either [on haskell.org](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) or [on stackage](https://www.stackage.org/) - the first one searches in all of hackage and runs hoogle 4 (if i recall correctly) the latter searches the restricted package repository stackage but runs hoogle 5

Comment: @epsilonhalbe From a newbie perspective, it's incredibly confusing that http://www.haskell.org/hoogle seems to be completely different from http://hoogle.haskell.org (the former doesn't find `=:`, whereas the latter does)

Comment: To make this complete, you can use hoogle, the stackage hoogle, [hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/), or [roll your own](https://gist.github.com/chrisdone/78c1c1c052a853697cf3b902de086172).

Comment: @FrankSchmitt yes it is confusing, sadly but there are different repositories (hackage/stackage) and not all of them are running the same version of hoogle i tend to use both as well as a local installation of hoogle (when I don't have internet connection)

Comment: but not nearly as confusing as finding the "right" packaging/testing/whatnot-utiltiy in javascript-land

Comment: @FrankSchmitt looks like `hoogle.haskell.org` isn't stable yet. Once it is, I reckon `haskell.org/hoogle` will just redirect to it.